# Querying many tables to one

Tags: python, google-bigquery

By doing it as it is I'm getting error `Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table.`
I know, I have table update limit:

`Maximum rate of table update operations: 1 operation every 2 seconds (insert, patch, update, jobs output).`

But my question is how should I handle it? By adding some delay after insert job in loop?

I have to update destination table from 500 federated tables (google drive sheets), I cannot use wilcards or multiple select at once because when one of users type string into integer field whole query will fail by getting fail parse error.

So I decided to loop it in python (then create cron job) by putting insert job for every table

Do you know any more effectient method for it?

**Edit1 code added**:

```
def insert(query, tableid, disposition):
job_body = {
 "configuration": {
  "query": {
   "query": query,
   "useLegacySql": True,
   "destinationTable": {
    "datasetId": "dataset",
    "projectId": "myproject",
    "tableId": tableid
   },
   "writeDisposition": disposition
  }
 }
}

query_request.insert(
    projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER,
    body=job_body).execute()

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    query = "SELECT * FROM [%s]"
    for table in table_list():
        if int(table['id'][-4:]) <= 600:
            insert(query % table['id'], 'users_data_p1', "WRITE_APPEND")
        else:
            insert(query % table['id'], 'users_data_p2', "WRITE_APPEND")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: *By doing it as it is...I decided to loop it in python* -it would help to see **it** (i.e., code).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having many separate `SELECT *` queries, each tries to append to one of the two destination tables `users_data_p1` or `users_data_p2`, I think you can try constructing a query that is a `UNION ALL` of all source tables, then do one `WRITE_APPEND` operation for `users_data_p1`, then another `WRITE_APPEND` for `users_data_p1`. That should help you through the rate limiting.

Basically that is, to add batching logic to your script.